# bus timetable android

Tags: android, timetable

For a project I'm trying to implement a bus time table Android Application. I'm fairly new to  Android Development and need to store the time tables in efficient way.

Are there any decent ways to implement a table that's clear when viewed in the application, and small enough in memory so that it runs smoothly?

Also, is there a simple way that once the table is created that by touching a button it automatically updates without creating a new activity? Ie your currently viewing a timetable for route 1 and by pressing a button you view route 2 etc.

Comment: Just a suggestion. Take a look at the calendar app and how you can swipe from month to month. This could work well rather than a button to switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an [Android Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) for the time table.

As for your update, you can just make a request to your content provider in `onResume()`.

Answer (score 0):

From http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_table-layout/

> You can also programmatically create and configure table layouts in
>   Java. This is done using the TableLayout and TableRow classes
>   (android.widget.TableLayout and android.widget.TableRow).

Comment: Ah thanks for that. I was thinking of using an SQLlite databases but I realized it wasn't suitable

Comment: You should pick one answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.